# TA-Lib installation Error: Must use python with unicode enabled

Tags: python, windows, module, installation, cython

when I try to install ta-lib(a technical analysis library coded originally in C) for Python using a wrapper for Python and Cython, I get an error message saying "Must use python with unicode enabled". I have already tried googling to no avail.

Here's the full error message:

```
    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ta-lib-master>python setup.py install
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    skipping 'talib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'talib' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
    /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\ms
    ys\1.0\local\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tctalib.c /Fobuild\
    temp.win32-2.7\Release\talib.obj
    talib.c
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_common.h(85) : fatal
    error C1189: #error :  Must use Python with unicode enabled.
    error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
    e"' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: @Ben You saved my day. Make it an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: Sure :) Glad it was useful. 

Comment moved to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python binary was compiled with Unicode disabled (`configure --enable_unicode=no`). NumPy *requires* a Python build with Unicode support enabled.

You'll have to install one that does have it enabled (the default).

If you find your Python has Unicode enabled after all (run `python`, type `print u''` and you get no errors), then the build system is failing to pick up the Python C headers from `C:\Python27\include` instead. Specifically, the `pyconfig.h` file could be missing:

```
$ grep -i unicode /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h
   Include/unicodeobject.h). */
/* Define as the integral type used for Unicode representation. */
#define PY_UNICODE_TYPE unsigned long
/* Define as the size of the unicode type. */
#define Py_UNICODE_SIZE 4
/* Define if you want to have a Unicode type. */
#define Py_USING_UNICODE 1
   supplied by Python itself. (see Include/unicodectype.h). */
```

Comment: I think my Python does have unicode enabled, do you have any how to solve the problem if it's indeed the latter issue?

Comment: @user1943079: Sorry, no, Windows build systems are not my forte, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much control you have over the code -- but trying to build my own code using numpy/ndarrayobject.h, the solution was to #include "Python.h" before including the ndarrayobject header.