# "error:Must use Python with unicode enabled" when compiling cuda_convnet in VS 2013

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, unicode, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda 2.7 as the python package and I'm trying to compile cuda_convnet (which is used for pylearn2 package) with vs 2013. But I get an error  saying "#error Must use Python with unicode enabled."

I understand that my python binary is compiled with unicode disabled as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123593/ta-lib-installation-error-must-use-python-with-unicode-enabled) question. But What I want to know is how to enable unicode in Anaconda in windows.

Comment: That sounds very unlikely. Anaconda includes a lot of packages that require Unicode—including NumPy, which is the main thing people use Anaconda for.

Comment: More likely you have two Python installations, and you're not using Anaconda's, you're using the other one.

Comment: How are you trying to compile `cuda_convnet`?

Comment: Yes I also feel that it is very unlikely. I use instructions in [this](http://vision.group.shef.ac.uk/wordpress/?p=1) page

Comment: In general, you will need to use VS 2008 to compile things against Python 2.7 (and 2010 to compile against Python 3).